# Can Sideshow Spelleater give you a golden hero power?

Tags: hearthstone

If I use a golden [Sideshow Spelleater](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/22372-sideshow-spelleater), will the copied hero power be golden?

Or alternatively, if I steal a hero power from a player with a golden hero, will my newly acquired hero ability be golden?

And what if my own hero is golden and I replace its ability with the opponent's non-golden hero ability?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Testing both golden and nongolden Sideshow Spelleater against the AI with my golden mage resulted in the nongolden giving the nongolden heropower as it was from my opponent, and the golden one gave me a golden hero power.

Now I managed to use a nongolden Sideshow Spelleater against a golden opponent, I found that it gave me a nongolden heropower.

In conclusion it is almost certain that the goldenness of the stolen heropower depends entirely on the goldenness of the Sideshow Spelleater.

[image]
[image]
[image]